# How to round the corners of canvas in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking to round the corners of an image drawn on the canvas.

My end result should look like this below image.
An image with rounded corners and drop shadow, I have managed to add the drop shadow.

[image: goal_image]

Here's my painter code so far.

```
class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;

  const ImagePainter(this.image);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    double shadowBlurRadius = 22.0;
    Color shadowColor = Colors.black38;

    //Adds a Drop Shadow
    canvas.drawPath(
      Path()
        ..addRect(Rect.fromPoints(
            Offset(0, 0), Offset(size.width + 15, size.height + 15))),
      Paint()
        ..color = shadowColor
        ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(
            BlurStyle.normal, (shadowBlurRadius * 0.57735 + 0.5)),
    );

    //Draw Image
    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: use `canvas.clipRRect` method before calling `canvas.drawImage`

Comment: Could you add an example of how to round the corners? would really appreciate that.

Comment: like i said: first call `clipRRect` then call `drawImage` - as a result your image will have round corners since only part within your `RRect` will be visible

Comment: Sure I will give it a try, Thaks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your canvas in `ClipRRect`.

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    child: //your canvas
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked! but it made my custom code in painter class unresponsive. but I managed to fix it by further wrapping it in a container and giving it shadow.